# When using Counterspell, do you add your spell attack or any other modifiers to your roll when trying to meet the DC?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, counterspelling

When using *counterspell*, do you add your spell attack or any other modifiers to your roll when trying to meet the DC?

Situation:

An enemy casts an 8th-level spell. You cast *counterspell* at base 3rd level, which means you have to roll to meet the DC (equal to 10 + the spell’s level). In this case, the DC is 10 + 8 = 18. When rolling for *counterspell*, you roll a 16. Can you add your spell attack modifier or any other modifier to the spellcasting ability check to pass the DC of 18?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Add your Spellcasting Ability Modifier to your d20 roll

The description of [*counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) says:

> If it is casting a spell of 4th level or higher, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell's level.

You will add your spellcasting ability modifier (i.e. Intelligence modifier for Wizards, Charisma modifier for Sorcerers and Warlocks, etc.) to your d20 roll.

Answer (score 7):

Not usually, [as Kelvin points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/151666/when-using-counterspell-do-you-add-your-spell-attack-or-any-other-modifiers-to/151669#151669), but other modifiers are possible:

1. Wizards of at least 10th level and the Arcane Tradition of Abjuration get Improved Abjuration, allowing them to add their proficiency bonus to ability checks made as part of casting spells such as dispel magic and counterspell.
2. Bards with the Jack of All Trades feature add half their proficiency bonus to any ability check that doesn’t already include it; this includes the ones for *dispel magic* and *counterspell*.
3. Features such as the *guidance* spell or Bardic Inspiration can be used to add additional dice on ability checks like these. (A bard’s Cutting Words can even do the opposite!)

Answer (score 7):

#### You add your spellcasting ability modifier only, with some notable exceptions.

*Counterspell* says:

> make an ability check using your spellcasting ability.

The rules for ability checks state:

> To make an ability check, roll a d20 and add the relevant ability modifier.

So the *general* rule is that we *only* add our spellcasting ability modifier to the d20 roll. But why don't we add our proficiency bonus?

The proficiency bonus is typically only added to an ability check when the check involves a particular skill. The rules for skills say (emphasis mine):

> Sometimes, the DM might ask for an ability check using a specific skill — for example, “Make a Wisdom (Perception) check.” At other times, a player might ask the DM if proficiency in a particular skill applies to a check. In either case, proficiency in a skill means an individual can add his or her proficiency bonus to ability checks that involve that skill. *Without proficiency in the skill, the individual makes a normal ability check*.

Since the description of *counterspell* calls for an *ability check*, not a check involving a particular skill, the proficiency bonus does not apply, per the emphasized portion in the quote above.

#### Exceptions supersede general rules.

*Dungeons & Dragons 5th Edition* includes a rule that is sometimes expressed as *specific beats general*. This rule is explained in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* and *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* so:

> The game also includes elements — class features, spells, magic items, monster abilities, and the like — that sometimes contradict a general rule. When an exception and a general rule disagree, the exception wins.

In light of this rule, we observe two notable exceptions to the general rule expressed in the first section.

#### The Bard's Jack of All Trades

At 2nd level, the Bard class receives the class feature Jack of All Trades, which says:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can add half your proficiency bonus, rounded down, to any ability check you make that doesn’t already include your proficiency bonus.

As noted in the first section, we typically *do not* add our proficiency bonus to the ability check for *counterspell*, so this ability check qualifies for the bonus from Jack of All Trades, allowing a Bard to add half their proficiency bonus to the ability check of *counterspell*.

#### The Abjuration Wizard's Improved Abjuration

At 10th level, the Abjuration Wizard receives the class feature Improved Abjuration:

> Beginning at 10th level, when you cast an abjuration spell that requires you to make an ability check as a part of casting that spell (as in *counterspell* and *dispel magic*), you add your proficiency bonus to that ability check.

So a 10th level (or higher) Abjuration Wizard can add their proficiency bonus to ability checks made for *counterspell*.

#### Any other feature that lets you modify an ability check.

We also see exceptions to the general rule in any feature that lets you modify an ability check.

At 14th the College of Lore Bard gets the feature Peerless Skill:

> Starting at 14th level, when you make an ability check, you can expend one use of Bardic Inspiration. Roll a Bardic Inspiration die and add the number rolled to your ability check. You can choose to do so after you roll the die for the ability check, but before the DM tells you whether you succeed or fail.

At 14th level the bardic inspiration die is a d10, but becomes a d12 at 15th level.

Comment: The lore bard exception makes a high level lore bard nearly the equal of an abjuration wizard for counterspell.  Just found this, and am glad I checked this answer out. 